# search for a pattern , change just the 3rd and 4th columns of a file using sed on that line

Tags: regex, perl

Below is the what I have tried

The `sed` command has to change the 3rd line's 3rd and 4th columns and intent is to change only line starting with `sox4d2`.

```
File content :
 
 sox4d4 ;/appl/m4d4/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
 sox4d5 ;/appl/m4d5/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
 sox4d2 ;/appl/m4d2/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
 
 
 Expected content 
 
 sox4d4 ;/appl/m4d4/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
 sox4d5 ;/appl/m4d5/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
 sox4d2 ;/appl/m4d2/current ;TEXTM30 ;TEXTM30 ;
```

I would like to change just the values of 3rd and 4th columns of line 3

Below is the sed I ran but here I am directly searching for string but not the column number:

```
    sed -i "/sox4d2 /s/TEXTMX40/TEXTM30/g", file.txt
```

I would like to run this command from perl script actually.  Below is the snippet in the perl script , but even here I didn't use the column number:

```
  my $db_host = "TEXTM30";
  my $ser=srnmain.intranet
  
  system(
    'ssh' => ('-q',$ser),
     sed => ( '-i',qq(/sox4d2/s/\bTEXTMX40\b/$db_host/),$dest_file),
  
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed` how about:

```
sed -i -E '/sox4d2 /s#([^;]+;[^;]+;)[^;]+;[^;]+#\1TEXTMX30 ;TEXTMX30 #' file.txt
```

If `perl` is your option, following will also work:

```
perl -F' ;' -i -ape '$F[2] = $F[3] = "TEXTMX30" if /sox4d2 /; $_ = join(" ;", @F)' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With shown samples could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. This should be more Generic solution, give line numbers in `line` variable, give column names in `columns` variable and give their respective values in `vals` variable with comma separated.

```
awk -v line="3" -v columns="3,4" -v vals="TEXTMX30,TEXTMX30" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(columns,arr1,",")
  num2=split(line,arr3,",")
  for(k=1;k<=num2;k++){
    lines[arr3[k]]
  }
  split(vals,arr2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    values[arr1[i]]=arr2[i]
  }
}
(FNR in lines){
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in values){ $i=";"values[i] }
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=" ;"} $1 == "sox4d2" {$3=$4="TEXTMX30"; $5=""} 1' file

sox4d4 ;/appl/m4d4/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
sox4d5 ;/appl/m4d5/current ;TEXTMX40 ;TEXTMX40 ;
sox4d2 ;/appl/m4d2/current ;TEXTMX30 ;TEXTMX30 ;
```

Comment: Here is chat link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228392/chat-with-learningcpp